# A new tab for a record Type!

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, administration, record-type

**Hello Folks,
             I have a question which might be more on the admin side of the force.com platform but involves development.**

**Question:** *If I create record types for an object, how can I create separate tabs for the same object but different record types. And, since they all are going to share the same fields, how can I distinguish the labeling?*

**I dont think this is currently possible, but I would like to know how can it be achieved?**

**What I have tried:** *I tried creating visualforce pages with enhanced lists but then in the enhanced list I can not specify the record type.*

***Please let me know how can I achieve this! Thank you for the help.***

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? You can't create multiple custom object tabs but you can create multiple visualforce tabs from the same page.

Comment: I have 3 record types for Accounts. I want separate tabs for each one of them!

Comment: I don't think this will work. Since the combination of the user’s profile and the record type determine which page layout is displayed for a user at the run time. That is to say that a user can only use one record type at one time. And there is no way to dynamically assign the record type for different users at run time.

Comment: Could you please shed some light on 'one record type at one time'? Any user will be working with only 1 record at one specific time.

Can I code something in Apex where I can grab records in a list for a specific 'RECORD TYPE'?! Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Actually you can do it. RecordTypeId is a field on the Object, and then you can give permissions to every tab.

Comment: You can definitely do this with a Visualforce page. Could you post the code you used for the VF approach you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to have separate Salesforce *List View* pages for each RecordTypes, e.g. trying to stick with the `enhancedList` component, you're probably out of luck without a lot of custom coding.

However, if you'd basically just like to replicate standard "Tab" page functionality, you could do this  a couple ways:

1. With Visualforce, using an extension controller to pull in only records of a desired RecordType, and then displaying the records however you'd like, such as with a simple `apex:pageBlockTable` looping over the records you queried for in the extension controller. Then create a separate Visualforce tab and corresponding page for each RecordType. You could probably optimize this process, if the desired "Tab" page output is the same for each RecordType, by abstracting the code for the extension controller where you query for just records of a particular RecordType, into a Visualforce Component, so that you could do something like this in each of your Visualforce Tabs:

   ```
   <apex:page>
       <c:recordTypeTab objectType="Account" recordTypeDeveloperName="Business_Account"/>
   </apex:page>
   ```
2. There are some 3rd party tools that could help you achieve this without a lot of custom code, such as [Skuid](http://www.skuidify.com).